# Select Within Quotes

Tags: web-mode, mark

Supposing I have my cursor resting somewhere in a bunch of text within quotes, is there a key binding that will mark or highlight just the text within the quotes so I can delete it?

This would be ideal for web-mode. Perhaps, if there's not already an emacs way of doing this, then maybe there's a way of doing in web-mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [expand-region](https://github.com/emacsmirror/expand-region) or [emacs-surround](https://github.com/ganmacs/emacs-surround) packages to select the text and then delete it.

Watch an intro to expand-region on: [Emacs Rocks](http://emacsrocks.com/e09.html).

Or take a look at the examples of emacs-surround on its [README](https://github.com/ganmacs/emacs-surround/blob/master/README.md) file.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun select-text-in-delimiters ()
  "Select text between the nearest left and right delimiters."
  (interactive)
  (let (start end)
    (skip-chars-backward "^<>([{\"'")
    (setq start (point))
    (skip-chars-forward "^<>)]}\"'")
    (setq end (point))
    (set-mark start)))
```